# How to hide parts of 3D objects that stick out of the back of other (complex) 3D objects?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, intersection, mesh

I'm rendering a complex 3D mesh with Three.js (an iliac bone). Then I'm rendering some simple spheres along with this mesh to mark certain points on the surface (where muscles would attach):

[image: front of the bone; the markers should be visible here]       [image: back of the bone; the markers should NOT be visible here]

The problem is, the mesh is quite thin in some areas, and the markers will stick out the back.

Assume that the marker coordinates are always closer to the front face of the mesh than the back face, and that the spheres always show more surface area / volume on the front of the mesh than on the back:

How could I hide the parts that extrude out the back without manually intervening for specific markers?

**Edit:** Here's a (naive?) way of how I might do it. I would like feedback on the feasibility of the idea, and (some pointers to writing) actual code to do it:

- for each marker sphere:

  - find all faces of the mesh that intersect with the sphere
  - compute all outward-facing normal vectors of those faces (vertex-normals? face-normals?)
  - compute all distances from the center of the face to the center of the sphere
  - add all those normal vectors, weighed by their respective distances
  - given the (normalized?) result vector, hide the hemisphere pointing in that direction

I'm not sure how to code any of those steps. Nor am I sure if this is even a sensible approach.

Comment: Idea 1: Draw hemispheres instead of spheres (`phiStart` and `phiLength` params: http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Geometries/SphereGeometry). Idea 2: Set an offset of the spheres on the `normal` depending on the sphere radius and bone thickness (you'll need that info) in the point where the sphere should be placed so it will not be visible on the other side.

Comment: @B0Andrew: Both fine ideas, but the most difficult part for both is: how to detect *in which direction* visibility should be restricted (by removing a hemisphere, or by moving the sphere in the other direction). Ideally this would be done automatically somehow by analyzing the geometry of the bone around those coordinates.

Comment: You should be able to access bone faces with `bone.geometry.faces`. Then each face should have `vertexNormals`. Take a look in `VertexNormalsHelper` code. This should give you a good start: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/helpers/VertexNormalsHelper.js

Comment: The problem with Three.js code is that it is poorly documented --- in this case, *not* documented. And I am far from an expert in geometry and 3D modeling. A piece of example code targeted at my specific problem would be useful. Nonetheless, I'll definitely have a look at the `VertexNormalsHelper` to see what I can make of it. Thanks!

Comment: @B0Andrew: Based on your link, I've written down how I might approach the problem, and added it to my original question. Feedback would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Draw hemispheres instead of full spheres.
Use `phiStart` and `phiLength` parameters of the [SphereGeometry](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Geometries/SphereGeometry) constructor.

The centers of the spheres will still be on the surface of the bone (a vertex).

The orientation of one sphere will be given by the `normal` calculated in the sphere origin.

Three.js already calculates the normals for a mesh in order to determine how light will bounce from the mesh. You can use the `VertexNormalsHelper` to display normals for your mesh:

```
var bone = ...; // bone mesh
var scene = ...; //your THREE.Scene
scene.add(new THREE.VertexNormalsHelper(bone));
```

The source code for `VertexNormalsHelper` can be found here:[VertexNormalsHelper](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/helpers/VertexNormalsHelper.js)

You have to calculate the difference angles between the normal vector and `oZ` axis so you obtain `difX` and `difY`. These are the ammounts you must rotate your sphere in the `X` and `Y` directions to make it perpendicular on the local surface of the bone.

Comment: Two questions: **[1]** What are 'face-normals', then? Intuitively, it feels like I should be using those. **[2]** Given a sphere, how to automatically find the normal vector that corresponds to it? Probably I will need more than one, and I'll have to take an average (otherwise, imagine a marker centered on a very small, but steep, local slope). Will this need to be a linear search on the geometry, or are there smarter ways to find them? Thanks!

Comment: The bone geometry is loaded with `STLLoader`, and is a `BufferGeometry`. It does not have a `faces` property, so the `VertexNormalsHelper` doesn't work on it. Also, I can't find any way to convert a `BufferGeometry` to a `Geometry`... :-/